# How to do simple math in an SQL SELECT query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to select all products whose fields conform to a simple mathematical expression (in my case, division).

**Example Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE (retail_price/invoice_price)>1.05
```

**Needs to be flexible:**
I need flexibility here because I wish to be able to define the expression as a string somewhere else and just pop it in the SQL query after the WHERE clause.

```
$expression = "(retail_price/invoice_price)>1.05";
$query = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE ".$expression." LIMIT 1";
```

**Notes:** 
- Data type of retail_price is VARCHAR 
- Data type of invoice_price is VARCHAR
- Not sure if VARCHAR is suitable for monetary values though..

Any suggestions? Because the above did not work for me. (Returned zero results)

Comment: What's the problem? That's exactly how you'd do it. If you're getting no results with this, then you've got nothing that has a 1.05 ratio of sale/invoice prices.

Comment: What is the data type of retail_price and invoice_price? It could be a rounding issue if you're not getting results when you should be.

Comment: The expression should match data in my table. But I'll double check. Good to know that the expression itself is correct though. Thanks.

Comment: Does INT / INT result in integer division?

Comment: @JustinSwartsel they are VARCHAR actually (not INT). I made them VARCHAR because they sometimes contain decimals. Is this acceptable?

Comment: Try to see what gives `retail_price/invoice_price` (type and result ) and change what needs change!!

Comment: @EricTurner that's not a good idea. Why not make the columns DECIMAL(m,n) if they can contain decimal values. VARCHAR is asking for trouble - what happens when there's a value like 'foo' in that column?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It could be a rounding problem (as @Justin said).
Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE (1.0 * retail_price / invoice_price) > 1.05
```

The idea is to force engine to manage floats (multiplying for float number 1.0).

**UPDATE**:
I see you've just edited data type to VARCHAR.
Anyway the result (for me) is the same: look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/298d3/2

Comment: Yes. You're absolutely right. The query is returning results with no problems. Great site by the way (sqlfiddle)! Bookmarked. The problem was elsewhere in an unrelated  part of the script. Hah. Thank you Marco and others!